# Como mostrar que se descargó un archivo en el navegador

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un inconveniente al descargar un archivo, pasa que lo descargo correctamente y lo guardo en desktop, pero el navegador (chrome) no muestra la animación. Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal? Adjunto mi código.

```
    Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
    Dim address As String = Server.MapPath("~/Docs/documento_creado/FichaProducto.pdf")
    Dim desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim fileName As String = desktop + "\FichaProducto.pdf"
    client.DownloadFile(address, fileName)
```

Comment: ¿Dónde esta la imagen en este Código? Si esta dentro del PDF nunca verás una animación en él ya que los PDF no pueden mostrar animaciones GIF ni de otro tipo...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes Preguntar Si el Archivo Existe de Esta Manera...

' Esto en el Método

```
If MFS.FileExist(filename) = True Then
        MsgBox("Existe")
    Else
        MsgBox("No Existe")
End If
```

' Y esto Declarar-lo Por Fuera del Método Pero Donde Tenga Acceso...

```
Public Function FileExist(ByVal FilePath As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim F As Object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    FileExist = F.FileExists(FilePath)
End Function
```